# On generating pdfs using itext pdf, CMYK image is producing pdfs of very large size

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext, cmyk

I am using Itext pdf to generate pdfs having images. For CMYK type JPEG images, i am getting pdfs of nearly double the size of the image used. But for the same image's RGB version, the pdf is nearly of the same size of the image.

I would like to know the exact reason behind the increase in size of the pdf. Please note that the pdf contains only the image and a few text comments.

Comment: Can you share an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a [CMYK JPEG image from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aChannel_digital_image_CMYK_color.jpg) with a file size of 714 KByte.

I've created a PDF file with nothing but this image. This resulted in a file size of 1.06 MB, of which 714 KByte consist of the original image and 373 KByte for the color space info that is needed when you introduce a CMYK image. Together that's about 1.06 MB, which means that the overhead of the PDF objects is really small.

I guess you overlook the fact that the PDF expects ICC-based Color space info along with CMYK JPEG images. I didn't see any other abnormal results when testing with the image I found on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I didnt know that PDF expects ICC-based Color space info along with CMYK JPEG images. Will the size of Color Space info increase with the size of image?

Comment: The color space info is needed to convert one color into another. It doesn't depend on the size of the image.

Comment: Do we have any APIs to compress a CMYK image? I need to generate a pdf with compressed images(be it CMYK or RGB). Its ok if it reduces the quality. I am able to compress RGB images by using ImageIO.getInstance(pdfContentByte, bufferedImage,quality) API. But I am not able to get the buffered image of CMYK images. Forgive my ignorance in Image Processing, but are CMYK images non compressable when writing to PDF?

Comment: No need to apologize, compression is complex (sometimes a compressed stream is larger than the original one). I'm going to split up my answer in two comments. [1.] iText doesn't compress images in the sense that it doesn't reduce the resolution. What you do with `ImageIO` happens outside iText, in Java. I'd need to test why CMYK wouldn't compress using Java myself and if time permits, I may do that, but I can't guarantee anything. Maybe you can post this as a general question unrelated to PDF to get the attention of the image experts.

Comment: [2.] In the latest iText version (iText 5.5.1), we added some functionality in response to a question on StackOverflow. When iText adds a JPEG image to a PDF, the image bytes are copied literally into the PDF and the compression filter is DCTDecode. However, you can also add an extra compression filter: FlateDecode. We've made this possible by using the `setCompressionLevel()` method on the image using a value that differs from "no compression" and the "default compression". Maybe you can gain some bytes by using that method. But again: compression is complex matter...

Comment: I used setCompressionLevel(), trying out values from 1 to 9. But the PDF size was not changing.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I feared. JPEG compression is already quite good, there's nothing much to gain by adding GZIP compression. You'll have to go down the path of further lossy compression.

Comment: @user3656458:Useful conversation ,finally did u reduced the PDF size or not?

Comment: I was unable to reduce the size of CMYK images. So I used ghostscript to compress the pdf after generation.